# Control a pivot table in Excel from Python

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I have an Excel file in pivot table format that is updated monthly. I want to make a script in Python that controls the pivot table in the xlsm so I can define columns, rows and values in the pivot table in Excel. Then I whis to extract the data as a pandas dataframe.

I dont find any information on Python interaction with xlsm pivot table. I have looked at xlwings but couldn't find anything, at least not at first glance.

Any help/suggestions?

Comment: Have you been here? https://trenton3983.github.io/files/solutions/2020-06-22_pivot_table_win32com/create_pivot_table_with_win32com.html

Comment: You can use Michal's link in connection with xlwings by using the `.api` attribute which gives you a pywin32 object, so you don't have to code all the boilerplate code yourself. See also: https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/missing_features.html

Comment: Thanks :) I check these two links out. Hopefully I can make something out of it..